# Add "selected" attr to options in different select "tag"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have one "table" with sizes. And want to add attr "selected" to "option" in all "selects in the document.

```
<select name="Size" id="size_11">
       <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
       <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
       <option value="38">38.5</option>
       <option value="39">39</option>
       <option value="40">40</option>
       <option value="40.5">40.5</option>
       <option value="41">41</option>
       <option value="41.5">41.5</option>
       <option value="42">42</option>
       <option value="43">43</option>
       <option value="43.5">43.5</option>
       <option value="44.5">44.5</option>
       <option value="45">45</option>
       <option value="45.5">45.5</option>
       <option value="46">46</option>
       <option value="46.5">46.5</option>
       <option value="47">47</option>
       <option value="48">48</option>
       <option value="48.5">48.5</option>
</select>
```

This works:

```
$('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() {
  $('option').removeAttr('selected').eq($(this).index()).attr('selected', ' ');
});
```

But it works only with the first "select" in the document Removing attr "selected" from all "option", but adding it only to an "option"s in first "select".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `option:nth-child` in the selector

```
$('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() {
  $('select > option').removeAttr('selected');
  $('select > option:nth-child('+($(this).index()+1)+')').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```js
$('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() {
  console.log($('select > option:nth-child('+($(this).index()+1)+')'));
  $('select > option').removeAttr('selected');
  $('select > option:nth-child('+($(this).index()+1)+')').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modal_sizes">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select name="Size">
  <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
  <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
  <option value="38">38.5</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
</select>
<select name="Size">
  <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
  <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
  <option value="38">38.5</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
</select>
<select name="Size">
  <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
  <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
  <option value="38">38.5</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
</select>
<select name="Size">
  <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
  <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
  <option value="38">38.5</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
</select>
<select name="Size">
  <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
  <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
  <option value="38">38.5</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sometimes it happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove the attribute since `multiple` attribute is not added updating the selected property will update the other elements `selected` property automatically. So use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to update the property of `option` selected based on the index.

```
$('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() {
  $('option').eq($(this).index()).prop('selected',true);
  // or $('option:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```js
$('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() {
  $('option').eq($(this).index()).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modal_sizes">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select name="Size" id="size_11">
  <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
  <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
  <option value="38">38.5</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
</select>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to remove the attribute the set attribute and remove the attribute from its sibling elements.

```
 $('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() { 
   $('option').eq($(this).index()).attr('selected', ' ').siblings().removeAttr('selected');
 });
```

```js
$('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() {
  $('option').eq($(this).index()).attr('selected', '  ').siblings().removeAttr('selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modal_sizes">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select name="Size" id="size_11">
  <option value="37" selected="">37</option>
  <option value="37.5">37.5</option>
  <option value="38">38.5</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but still with only one select in document (the first one), and doesnt change all proper option's attr in other selects

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue here is that you are selecting all the options.  Not just the options in your particular row.  You should probably do this in addition to using prop instead of changing the attr.

```
$('#modal_sizes tr').click(function() {
  $('option', this).prop('selected', false).eq($(this).index()).prop('selected', true);
});
```

The scoped selection being `$('option', this)`